# Azure Service Fabric: Stateful sharding

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Very new to service fabric, using it for a day now and have implemented some other services. Trying to port current code over as POC

I am facing an issue attempting to deploy a stateful service that is partitioned. I am setting the partition count to a value such as 3 on a 1 node cluster. I want to shard data that is retrieved on the start of the application between these partitions.

For the real app it will go to the database on startup, pull a list of things that it will process throughout the day. These all have unique ids that can be hashed and modulo to run on a particular partition

E.g.

```
var fakeIds = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var idsToRunWith = new List<int>();

var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
var paritionList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(new Uri("ServiceName"));
var numberOfPartitions = paritionList.Count;

foreach (var fakeId in fakeIds)
{
     var partitionIndex = fakeId % numberOfPartitions;
     if (paritionList[partitionIndex].PartitionInformation.Id == Context.PartitionId)
     {
         idsToRunWith.Add(fakeId);
     }
}
```

The above is just an example of what i have done

Does anyone know of a better way to do this in service fabric?

Do I need to create another service that loads these things from the database and forwards them to the service on correct partition? -- trying not to do this as it feels unnecessary

The application is long ruining and these things to process are assigned weeks in advance

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/10/13/understanding-service-fabric-partitions/) blog help you?

Comment: I did read this blog but was not useful for the usecase above. It just feels like it would be common to shard data given some startup requirements and there would be a solution already. I might not be thinking in the correct mind set and need to approach the problem differently but will see what people think

Comment: maybe this video helps? it comes with slides and sample code. https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/10/15/techdays-2017-talk-slides/

Comment: Are you using Uniformed partitioning schema? Are you interested in service to perform it's own initialization i.e. in `RunAsync` method read the data that would fit the partition?

Comment: @LoekD - love those slides. I think that has really helped me. I think I will have another look at my code when i get time to read through the slides and example code

Comment: @OlegKarasik that is exactly what I was looking to do/am doing. Just wondering if i am implementing this wrong and actually there is a much better setup that i have not seen. Will look through the slides above and see what i find and update the post if i find a better way for others to also see

Comment: @StevIeP I think you can use the following: `StatefulService` has a property called `Partition`. In `RunAsync` method you can convert `this.Partition.PartitionInfo` to [Int64RangePartitionInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.int64rangepartitioninformation?view=azure-dotnet) and use its `LowKey` and `HighKey` values to get id range that has to be imported from the database. Then you can use whatever DA technology you have to import the data in the reliable state of the partition.